# Is it a good idea to GPG sign old git commits?

Tags: git, gnupg

I just realized that I forgot to tell git to use my GPG key. I had made a number of commits without signing them. Should I go back and sign them?

I am not referring to whether or not I should sign tags, but I decided to sign commits themselves. I don't believe I can think of any reason not to, other than having a corrupted git history that may or may not be what I wrote. I trust GitHub to not mess around with my git history and I am the only author of about 99% of my projects, so given that, should I do so?

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits), so I know now it is possible, but philosophically speaking, should I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the commits have already been published, you *should not* rewrite them for any purpose (except removing accidental data leaks), as this would change their commit IDs. (Remember that each commit's ID is based on SHA-1 hashes of its content *and* its parent commit.)

That means it'd require rewriting (and resigning) *all* subsequent commits, and would cause troubles for anyone who had already fetched any of those commits.

But for the same reason, you **don't need to** sign those old commits explicitly, at least not for data integrity purposes. Since each commit contains SHA-1-based IDs of its parents, verifying any single commit will also implicitly verify *its entire history* via the hash chain. It doesn't matter that the chain is a little longer or shorter.

On the other hand, if you don't trust SHA-1 for security, then you should consider commit signing entirely useless, since commits' file contents are *also* referred to by SHA-1 hashes. The only thing you sign directly (and not a hash thereof) is the commit message.