# Why git commit doesn't recognize --amend on git Windows?

Tags: command-line, shell, git

I am trying to follow the suggestion [Can you GPG sign old commits?](https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits/1123928#1123928)

```
λ git rebase --exec 'git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S' -i develop
```

But getting

```
error: unknown option `amend'
```

I am running git version `2.23.0.windows.1`

Comment: what shell are you using? git-bash? my first guess is it doesn't like your single-quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the use of `λ` in the prompt string I guess you're using cmder as the terminal with cmd as the shell. In cmd [single quotes aren't the quoting symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714) so the exec string isn't passed as a single parameter. You need to change to double quotes:

```
git rebase --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit -n -S" -i develop
```

Or better change to powershell or other shells (you should already have bash if you install git on Windows). They recognize `'` as the quote character so you don't need to change anything, and you get more features