# Rewrite and Resign git commit-history with git-filter-repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have an existing private git-repository (with two branches), hosted on GitHub. I plan to make it public, but I don't want to make public the author email-address. So, **the plan is to rewrite the commit-history, by replacing the `<old-author-email>` with the `<new-author-email>`, and resign the commits.** Also, I want to maintain the time-stamps (this is important for me!).

So, based on extensive research I have come-up with the following steps:

1. Clone the repository on my local machine.
2. Create a python-3.x virtual-environment, and run `pip install git-filter-repo`. ([source](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md#installation-via-pip))
3. Create a `.mailmap` file in the repository `WORKING_DIR`, with the email remapping information. ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap))
4. Run `git-filter-repo --force --mailmap .mailmap`. ([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58263677/4687256), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65337283/4687256))
5. Somehow resign the new-commits !!
6. Then run `git push origin <your_branch_name> --force`, to rewrite the remote commit-history. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610763/4687256))

   - If this step doesn't work, I would simply delete the original Github repository; Create a new one with the same name, and then push the local-repository to it.

The above steps (*until step-4*), rewrite the author-email and recompute the hashes, but discard the signatures. The documentation says: ([source](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_limitations))

> Since git filter-repo calls fast-export and fast-import to do a lot of the heavy lifting, it inherits limitations from those systems ... **commits get rewritten meaning they will have new hashes; therefore, signatures on commits and tags cannot continue to work and instead are just removed** (thus signed tags become annotated tags)

So, to resign the commits, I found the following method ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1368424/526996)).

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' HEAD
```

But using `git filter-branch` is not recommended ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/4687256)), even by Git's own documentation ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_warning)).

**Questions**:

- And, is there a way to rewrite author-email and resign the new-commits, all using `git-filter-repo`?
- And if no! then, how to rewrite the author-email over the entire commit-history and resign the new-commits? (a better way than mine!)

Answer (score 2):

> **This method DOESN'T work if the repository has multiple branches**. So, before getting started, merge all secondary branches in to the primary-branch (usually `master`/`main`), as per your requirement. And then delete all the secondary-branches. (both in the local and the remote repositories)

I came up with a possible solution:

1. Clone the repository on my local machine.
2. Create a python-3.x virtual-environment, activate it, and then run `pip install git-filter-repo GitPython`.
3. `cd <repo-directory>/../`, i.e., the immediate parent-directory of the local-repository's `WORKING_DIR`
4. **Run the following python-script**: This will create a `.mailmap` file, right outside the `<repo-directory>`, with all the unique author/committer-name and email combinations appearing in the said repository's commit history - to be replaced with the `NEW_NAME` and `NEW_EMAIL`. (Further edit the code to exclude certain names/emails from being rewritten)

> ```
> from git import Repo
>
> repo_path = '<repo-directory>'
> repo = Repo(repo_path)
>
> commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())
> unq = set()
> for cmt in commits_list:
>     unq.add((cmt.committer.name, cmt.committer.email))
>     unq.add((cmt.author.name, cmt.author.email))
>
> NEW_NAME = "<new-author-name>"
> NEW_EMAIL = "<new-author-email>"
>
> lines = list()
> for c in unq:
>     lines.append(f"{NEW_NAME} <{NEW_EMAIL}> {c[0]} <{c[1]}>\n")
>
> with open(".mailmap", "w") as f:
>     f.writelines(lines)
> ```

5. `cd <repo-directory>`, and then run `git-filter-repo --mailmap ../.mailmap`. --> Running this command, for some reason, seems to remove the `remote` repository links, i.e. `git remote -v` returns nothing.
6. To reset the repository's remote, run `git remote add origin <remote-repo-url>`
7. **DON'T DO THIS: if you have multiple branches** To sign the commits, run `git filter-branch --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@";' HEAD`. Also, you might have to add an `-f` flag to make it work. <strike>for the branch separately, i.e. you will need to checkout into each branch and run the said command.</strike>

   - After performing the above steps, I ran `git fsck --full --strict` and got no errors. So, I think it worked fine!
   - **But is there a better way to check for the repository's integrity?**
8. Finally, run `git push origin <primary-branch> --force` to over-write all the remote branches with the updated commit history.